# "Force check now" in zabbix 2.2.1

Tags: zabbix

If any of you know if there is a possibility of implementation "Force check now" just like in Nagios? the problem is that some check have a high update interval time for example 10 minutes, and sometimes there is a need to test something quickly.

In Zabbix Jira i found something like that's : https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-473

Please give me some advice

Regards
Mick

Comment: There is currently no such feature and ZBXNEXT-473 is the correct place to track its progress.

Answer (score 2):

On the server, there is a command `zabbix_get' which exactly try the value of the key immediately.

```
sudo zabbix_get -s hostNameOrIP -k keyName
```

So easy!

Comment: Yeah but there is some way to do this from GUI ?

Comment: @Mick, I don't know any way in graphical except setting time interval for 5 seconds or less or more in item's configurations.

Comment: This won't actually make the zabbix_server check the item, and put it in the database. It will only check it from the command line and return the data to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

One (quirky) way might be to visit the configuration for your problematic host, then choose *Triggers*, then configure the alarming trigger, choose *Expression constructor* and from there *Test*.

I know this might not perform exactly what you are after for, but it's better than nothing.